# How to make html text rise above absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I am trying to get some hardcoded text to show above a absolutely positioned element that is an image using z-index to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
.repay {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#444;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:40px 0px 30px 0px;
    z-index:10001;
}

.sliderbubble-repay {
    width:227px;
    height:140px;
    background:url('../images/white-sliderbubble.png') no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:119px;
    left:255px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements need to have `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;` for `z-index` to work.

Try adding `position:relative;` to `.repay`